# Identify value changes from a control in sub form in Angular

Tags: angular9

I have the component hierarchy as below.

[image]

componentA.ts is as below

```
  this.componentAForm= this.formBuilder.group({
  componentBForm: this.formBuilder.group({
    componentCForm: this.formBuilder.group({
      control1: new FormControl(''),
      control2: new FormControl('')
    }),
```

ComponentA.html is as below

```
<componentB [formGroup]="componentAForm.controls.componentBForm"></componentB>
```

ComponentB.ts is as below

```
 this.componentBForm= this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
```

componentB.html is as below

```
<componentC [formGroup]="componentBForm.controls.componentCForm"></componentC>
```

Now my problem is I need to access the valuechanges in formGroupC inside componentB and do something inside it. Meanwhile while I access the formGroupA in Component A, It should be possible to access all changed (current values of formGroup hierarchy). How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the code in HTML

In component B, you can write this

```
componentBForm.controls.componentCForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => { whatever });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How ever I cannot do this. I need the valueChanges for that particular control

Comment: If you want a formControl from componentCForm, you can do something like this

`code`
((componentBForm.controls.componentCForm) as FormGroup).controls.componentCFormControlName.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => { whatever });

Comment: I will try that thank you. If this works as expected this is what I want

Answer (score 1):

Implement ControlValueAccessor in your components. So those will become custom controls.

https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: This is little new to me. Any way thanks. I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

What I tried to do is, inside `ngOnInit()` inside componentB I have created a tempFormGroup for formGroupC and the valuechanges will be as below.

```
   ngOnInit(){
    this.componentBForm= this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
    this.tempcomponentCForm= this.componentBForm.controls.componentCForm as FormGroup;
    this.tempcomponentCForm.controls.control1.valueChanges.subscribe({
    this.tempcomponentCForm= this.componentBForm.controls.componentCForm as FormGroup;//this will allow the future changes //Whatever I want to do
      });

    }
```

But in componentB.html

```
<componentC [formGroup]="omponentBForm.controls.componentCForm"></componentC >
```

It seems works for now. Some one please suggest the best practice towards this and possible challenges